# Restore/undo fsutil deletejournal on NTFS driver

Tags: windows, backup, exchange-2013

In order to return an Exchange 2013 system to life, I had to resolve a full disk.  So full that I couldn't even create a backup.

So I used fsutil to delete the journal, which freed 330MB and allowed me to run the system backup which cleared out the transaction logs.

I can't find much on the deletejournal command, but can someone tell me do I have to RECREATE the journal after my backup is done (and I have lots of free space again)?  Or is it automatically recreated?  (It's a Windows 2008 server0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange does not require a usn journal. And if your backup software relies on the usn journal, it will either recreate it, or tell you to create it. Normally it just creates it.

You can leave it disabled.

Comment: I'm using Windows Server Backup (built into windows)...